# How to login users that are encrypted on wordpress?

Tags: ios, wordpress, encryption

I'm creating an iPhone app that accesses data stored on a site that is hosted by wordpress. The users that are stored within wordpress have encrypted passwords, how would one go about authenticating the user? Would I need to use any certain code or would a json plugin on wordpress automatically authenticate the password without any input from my end?

Comment: Without clearly understanding your intention, WordPress has XML-RPC enabled, you can use this to authenticate from your iOS app.  You may find it simpler to install a JSON-RPC plugin on WordPress and use AFNetworking from iOS

Comment: I am intending to use the list of users stored on my wordpress account to sign in to my app. 
So a login screen will appear when the app is opened and the only way to access the content within my application is to 1) have an account on my website and 2) have the right username/password combination which is encrypted on my wordpress host. i'm just not sure if I needed to do any coding on my end to decrypt the password first (if even possible)?